# Phonegap Jquery Android save image from external URL to www folder

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to download an external image in to www folder for android using jquery/Phonegap

could anyone please help me to  download an image from external URL and save it to the project folder(www) for an android app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileTranser.download to get the file.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_download

but you won't be able to save it to the www folder as it is read only (part of the app bundle on iOS). You'll have to save it on internal or external storage.

Comment: could you please elaborate, what would be the target_path of file transfer service of phonegap to save it to internal storage and external storage? and also how can i display that saved image in different screen?